# What is the difference between *.ttf and *.ttc fonts on Ubunt 20.04?

Tags: fonts

I have specific *.ttf fonts in `/usr/local/share/fonts` on Ubuntu 20.04.
I also have a *.ttc fonts in the `/usr/local/share/fonts` path.

In **Ubuntu**, can I delete the three *.ttf fonts and keep the *.ttc font?

I read that `*.ttc` is a newer format that contains *many* fonts in a single file.

1. Can you explain in very simple terms what `*.ttc` is and how it is different from `*.ttf`?
2. Does this mean I can remove the `*.ttf` files for a font, if I have that font's `*.ttc` file installed?

   For example, can I simply delete these three files...

   - `cambriab.ttf`
   - `cambriai.ttf`
   - `cambriaz.ttf`

   ...if I have...

   - `cambria.ttc`

   ?

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127828/differences-and-similarities-between-ttf-and-ttc-fonts

Comment: Assuming you mean `/use/share/fonts`, files there are typically owned by packages and will come back the next time the owning packages are upgraded/reinstalled. So why do you want to remove random files owned by packages?

Comment: Please leave questions regarding moderation of the question out of the question and use META for clarification.

Comment: @muru, I am asking about downloaded purchased fonts or open source (free as in beer) fonts that a user wants to make available on their system. These fonts are usually not packaged in a *.deb file. However, they can be placed in `/use/share/fonts` to make them globally available to all users on a system. (Of course, you can put them in `/etc/skel/.fonts` but that would just make redundant copies each time you create a new user).

Comment: The place for administrator-installed non-packaged fonts is in `/usr/local/share/fonts`, not `/usr/share/fonts`.

Comment: I didn't know that! I'll move them to `/usr/local/share/fonts`. However, my question is do I need to the `*.ttf` fonts or does the `*.ttc` fonts contain all of the `*.ttf` fonts? (Of course, I could try it myself and find out, but I thought someone already knows the answer, and it would help others who have the same question).